# Error when showing a jpeg image with GD library inside a webpage

Tags: php, header, gd

I've created an image class to display and convert images on the site with GD library. when I want to show jpeg images without any HTML code in the site
everything will be OK because I set header('Content-Type: image/jpeg').
My code is like below:

```
$filepath = 'path to the image file';
$info = getimagesize( $filepath );
$this->type = $info[2];
if( $this->type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) 
{
    $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath); // set the resource image
} 
   if( $this->type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG )
   {
    $type = 'image/jpeg';
   }
 header('Content-Type: ' . $type );
  if( $this->type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG )
  {
    imagejpeg( $this->image );
   }
```

This code works perfectly, but how should I show images if I want to show them inside HTML codes (ob_start did not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request that script from a different file like any regular image:

```
<img src="path/to/the/file/that/outputs/the/image.php">
```

Comment: I appreciate it! My problem has been solved, but I have a new problem it takes so much time (2-3 seconds) to load the page that contains only one image. How should I solve this problem? Is there any solution for that? thanks in advance

Comment: That's impossible to answer. Look at your browser tools (Firebug/Web Inspector/whatever else you're using) to figure out *why* it's taking so long to load.